# In the following sentence, 多分 indicates maybe or probably?

Tags: meaning, expressions

> 多分俺は、今でもアリスを愛してる。
>   多分、世界で一位タイなくらい愛してる。

He's saying that maybe he still loves Alice.

How much does he love her? Is it "maybe" or "probably"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How much does he love her?

You can't exactly judge that based on these two sentences, but your translation is missing something important about what is said. Setting aside probably/maybe and using [a dictionary definition of 多分](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%A4%9A%E5%88%86),

> 多分俺は、今でもアリスを愛してる。 多分、世界で**一位タイなくらい**愛してる。
>   I probably still love Alice. I probably love her **as much as the joint winner(s)**.

「一位タイ」 is usually used [when talking about sports](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/3340551.html), but here it's used figuratively to refer to the ones he loves the most in the world. The 「タイ」 comes from the English word "tie", in this sense:

> **noun**
>   [**5**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tie) A result in a game or other competitive situation in which two or more competitors or teams have the same score or ranking; a draw.
>   *‘there was a tie for first place’*

Comment: How would you translate the second part then? (without saying joint winner). the other girl is Anne.

Comment: @Mercurious If you interpret the analogy to sports 1:1, he 多分 loves Alice as much as Anne (and maybe others because there can be a tie between two or more competitors.) I'm not a native English speaker and that is the best translation I can come up with.

Comment: and it's maybe or probably?

Comment: 「多分」は maybe より probably に近いと思います。「多分」は「もしかして」「かもしれない」より可能性が高いです。

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ 上のコメントはどう思いますか。一つの「多分」より不確実でしょう？

Comment: @siikamiika どうでしょう・・「たぶん」を二回言うと、より不確実なのか、より確実なのか・・どっちだろう、ちょっとわかりません・・また日本語で書いちゃった、ごめんｗ

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ そうですか。ならそのコメントを消します。意見ありがとうございます！（日本語でいい！勉強になります。）

Comment: Siika, could you give me your translation of the comment you upvoted?  (I may be missing something. Just that one, I perfectly understanf the second one).

Comment: @Mercurious ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ says that 「多分」 is closer to "probably" than "maybe" so to answer your question `and it's maybe or probably?`, "probably" is a better translation for it. ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ also says that expressions like 「もしかして」「かもしれない」 mean a lower probablility than 「多分」 and are thus closer to "maybe" (but not exactly maybe).

Comment: Could you retranslate the sentence accordingly?

Comment: @Mercurious It already uses "probably" so I don't know what I should retranslate

Comment: Just to know if you wanted to change something. Well, then it's in between probably and maybe, leaning towards probably. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds to me like the 一位タイ part means 'tying for first in the world', i.e. his love is just as strong as whatever other random person might otherwise be in first place. Not as much as he loves someone else besides Alice, but as much as someone else loves their love.

Comment: @Sjiveru Hmm, you're right. Maybe that part isn't directly comparing to somebody. However, questioner said in comments that there is another girl so I'm not sure if it changes the meaning in this case

Comment: @siikamiika  Since he says「世界で一位」, I'm less inclined to think of it as a specific other person. At least without context, 'A tie with the person I love most in the world' is believable, but I think 'A tie with the most anyone in the world loves' is more likely.